# ant - Disable Ivy to fetch dependency on every run

Tags: java, maven, ant, apache-spark, ivy

I am executing few of my custom Spark workers having a dependency on other libraries. Every time I execute them using `spark-submit`, Ivy tries to fetch latest dependency from internet, which takes some significant time in the beginning.
Is there any flag to disbale this fetching everytime? I mean, once Ivy caches the dependency, can we disable it for next times?

Answer (score 0):

Set useCacheOnly on the resolve task to true, it's default value is false.

More Info http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/resolve.html

This would be similar to mvn -o (offline mode of maven)

Comment: My ivysettings.xml is getting loaded from a 3rd party jar file. How can I override values inside it? Also, is there any command line flag we can pass to it?

Following are the logs when I execute it:
Ivy Default Cache set to: /Users/rootcss/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /Users/rootcss/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/Users/rootcss/infrastructure/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies......